# Duplicate zip entry [57.jar:android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.class]

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to solve one problem for a few days.
When I run my app, I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/AminSupportGroup/
app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] 
(Can't read [/Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/
AminSupportGroup/app/
build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/55.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
 (Duplicate zip entry [55.jar:android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.class]))
```

My module:app build.gradle where i think there is the problem :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
 applicationId "com.aminertebat.aminsupportgroup"
 minSdkVersion 16
 targetSdkVersion 28
 versionCode 1
 versionName "1.0.22"
 multiDexEnabled true
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
 release {
   minifyEnabled false
   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
 }
}
compileOptions {
 targetCompatibility 1.8
 sourceCompatibility 1.8
 }
}

ext {
BUTTERKNIFE = '8.8.1'
FAB = '1.6.4'
FIREBASE = '9.0.2'
MATERIAL_DIALOG = '0.9.1.0'
MATERIAL_DRAWER = '5.7.0'
MATERIAL_EDIT_TEXT = '2.1.4'
PLAY_SERVICE = '9.0.2'
SLIDING_TUTORIAL = '1.0.3'
SUPPORT_LIBRARY = '28.0.0'
RETROFIT = '2.2.0'
SMART_TAB_LAYOUT = '1.6.1'
EVENT_BUS = '3.0.0'
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${SUPPORT_LIBRARY}"
  implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${SUPPORT_LIBRARY}"
  implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${SUPPORT_LIBRARY}"
  implementation "com.android.support:design:${SUPPORT_LIBRARY}"
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
  implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1"
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
  implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${BUTTERKNIFE}"
  annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${BUTTERKNIFE}"
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
  implementation 'com.github.myinnos:AppFontChanger:1.0'
  implementation 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
  implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar'
  implementation 'com.adpdigital.push:chabok-lib:2.13.2'
  //implementation 'com.stepstone.apprating:app-rating:2.3.0'
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Have you tried to update all your dependencies to the latest versions?